# Create a JSON file by reading a mySQL table in java

Tags: java, mysql, json, select, jdbc

I want to select my data's table and store its content inside a `JSON` file. But my `JSON` file content only the last row of my table multiple time. Can you help me to identify where i'm wrong? Thank you...

Here is a part of my java code :

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

 try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, utilisateur, motDePasse);
    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT idUser, emailUser, motPassUser FROM utilisateur;");
    result = preparedStatement.executeQuery("SELECT idUser, emailUser, motPassUser FROM utilisateur;");

    obj = new JSONObject();
    array = new JSONArray();

    while (result.next()) {
        obj.put("id", result.getInt("idUser"));
        obj.put("email", result.getString("emailUser"));
        obj.put("password", result.getString("motPassUser"));
        array.add(obj);
    }

    try {
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("user.json");
        file.write(((JSONArray) array).toJSONString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {

} finally {
    if (result != null) {
        try {
            result.close();
        } catch (SQLException ignore) {
        }
    }
    if (preparedStatement != null) {
        try {
            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException ignore) {
        }
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

And this the output of my JSON file :

```
[{"id":3,"email":"tindongabou@gmail.com","password":"ludovic1992"},
{"id":3,"email":"tindongabou@gmail.com","password":"ludovic1992"},
{"id":3,"email":"tindongabou@gmail.com","password":"ludovic1992"}]
```

It contents only the last row of my table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create JSON object inside while loop as

```
while (result.next()) {

obj = new JSONObject();

        obj.put("id", result.getInt("idUser"));

        obj.put("email", result.getString("emailUser"));

        obj.put("password", result.getString("motPassUser"));

        array.add(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this line inside your while loop -

```
obj = new JSONObject();
```

Comment: can you please accept it as answer if it is working.